# AttributeError: 'QComboBox' object has no attribute 'setPlaceholderText' How do I fix this?

Tags: python, qcombobox

How do you do that? Because I am trying to run a rcon game tool.
This command "python3 isrt.py" gives me this,

```
<16:43:10> "Cougarxr7": python3 isrt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "isrt.py", line 3392, in <module>
    mgui = maingui()
  File "isrt.py", line 252, in __init__
    self.gui.setupUi(self)
  File "/home/cougarxr7/Programs/isrt/ISRT_v0.8.1_Linux-Mac/ISRT_v0.8.1/bin/isrt_gui.py", line 1857, in setupUi
    self.retranslateUi(ISRT_Main_Window)
  File "/home/cougarxr7/Programs/isrt/ISRT_v0.8.1_Linux-Mac/ISRT_v0.8.1/bin/isrt_gui.py", line 1866, in retranslateUi
self.dropdown_select_server.setPlaceholderText(_translate("ISRT_Main_Window", "Select Server&quot￼)
AttributeError: 'QComboBox' object has no attribute 'setPlaceholderText'
```

How do I fix this error?
Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Qt did you import QComboBox from?

Comment: Thanks for replying please read my comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QComboBox does not have a placeholder text option but you can achieve this by doing

```
self.dropdown_select_server.setEditable(True)
self.dropdown_select_server.lineEdit().setPlaceholderText(_translate("ISRT_Main_Window", "Select Server&quot"))
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I need to explain myself better.
I am not a developer, I am a user trying to get this program to work on Ubuntu 20.04. Here is the link to the program support ticket, mines is 24.
http://www.isrt.info/?page_id=661?support_page=open_ticket&ticket_id=24&auth_code=jegOl9fpt9
If you can please read what Issues I faced trying to get this program to work. I've included screen shots there of the issues I faced.As of now I cannot create a symbolic link for this program to python.
I do not have Qt installed.
At this time setPlaceholder error is what is what I am facing.

Comment: This problem has been solved>
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.14.1)<This version does not support QComboBox. 
Running this in terminal fixed this problem.
sudo python3 -m pip install pyqt5==5.15.4
Please mark this question as solved!